# Gradle 3.1.0 Error

Tags: android

we are updated the Gradle 3.1.0 then Following Errors Occurs.

1. Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2. Warning: The rule

   > -keep public class *extends java.lang.annotation.Annotation {
   >      *;
   >   }

   uses extends but actually matches implements.

How to Fix this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. On topic and how to ask apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I guess you are talking about Android Studio 3.1? Gradle would have a much higher version number 4.4 or later.

Comment: i am using the Gradle version for distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

Answer (score 1):

same issue. delete your configuration in your project proguard-rules.pro.
just like this

```
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-printconfiguration
-keep,allowobfuscation @interface android.support.annotation.Keep
-keep @android.support.annotation.Keep class *
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep *;
}
```

it's already in progurad's global configuration.